# Gmock returning instances of new objects

Tags: googlemock

I have a MockWidgetFactory. I want to return new MockWidgets instances when createWidget is called, this works fine for when I expect a single call:

```
EXPECT_CALL(*mock_widget_factory_, createWidget(_, _))
.WillOnce(Return(new MockWidget));
```

But when I am expecting multiple calls, I am seeing that the same MockWidget is returned:

```
EXPECT_CALL(*mock_widget_fatory_, createWidget(_, _))
.Times(4)
.WillRepeatedly(Return(new MockWidget));
```

I know this because in source:

```
IWidget* widgetA = WidgetFactory().createWidget(3, 4);
IWidget* widgetB = WidgetFactory().createWidget(5, 6);
IWidget* widgetC = WidgetFactory().createWidget(10, 12);
IWidget* widgetD = WidgetFactory().createWidget(20, 23);
```

I see widgetA, widgetB, widgetC, and widgetD as all pointing to the same address.

However, if I break this expect statement into a sequence, I am seeing that the four MockWidgets are different:

```
{
    InSequence createWidgets;

    EXPECT_CALL(*mock_widget_fatory_, createWidget(_, _))
    .WillOnce(Return(new MockWidget));

    EXPECT_CALL(*mock_widget_fatory_, createWidget(_, _))
    .WillOnce(Return(new MockWidget));

    EXPECT_CALL(*mock_widget_fatory_, createWidget(_, _))
    .WillOnce(Return(new MockWidget));

    EXPECT_CALL(*mock_widget_fatory_, createWidget(_, _))
    .WillOnce(Return(new MockWidget));
}
```

Obviously, having an expect statement per MockWidget is not very graceful, so what am I missing about WillRepeatedly that isn't allowing me to return distinct instances of MockWidget?

Answer (score 0):

You've probably already found out the answer by now. Still, for future seekers:

Use `ReturnNew<T>` instead of `Return`.

A quick directed search in GitHub can give you enough examples on how to use it:
https://github.com/search?l=C++&q=WillRepeatedly+ReturnNew&type=Code

---

p.s. A totally sideways piece of advice: assumption is one of a programmer's biggest enemies (in this case the assumption that Return will always evaluate what it is passed). It never hurts to skim through the docs of a new framework, even if you can get it up and running by just following a tutorial. This is especially true when you inherit legacy code based on a framework. The extra day to look around its doc files will save you weeks later.

Check this out for returning values in gmock:
https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/cheat_sheet.md#returning-a-value